# Why is share field editable?

Tags: discussion, sharing

Today I've noticed that share dialog's field is editable and I wondered what reasons could be behind of this logic?

[image]

Comment: What would be a good reason to _disable_ it?

Answer (score 7):

Possibly so its contents can be made automatically selected, reliably, across all platforms.

I wouldn't trust an input field with the `readonly` attribute to be universally selectable. While on all desktop browsers I just tested [it is](http://jsfiddle.net/nsj9v20j/)), you don't know what mobile clients are going to do with it.

That's just speculation though, not an official answer.

Comment: How about `<input readonly="readonly" />` ?

Comment: @abforce see my second pargraph

Comment: I can say that in the past (haven't tested recently) I had issues selecting `readonly` fields on Android. Though I honestly can't see how using a text field is an issue in the first place.